# Google apps script timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, timestamp

I am building a GAS timestamp function in google spreadsheet which will change the timestamp whenever I revise the cell value in column 10. However, The cell I'd revise now is filled with **IFS function**, which actually will change itself. The IFS function results to the original timestamp function stop working cause literally the cell value has not changed. Wanna ask if there's any way that I can solve this problem, so that GAS and spreadsheet function could work together smoothly.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col == 10 && row >1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Sheet 1" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 3).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review the IFS formula **precedent** dependencies to find which cells are actually edited by a user then, instead of looking for "edits" on the cells with that formula use the **precedent cells**.

i.e. Let sayt that you have the following formula in `B1`.

```
=A1+1
```

instead of looking for "edits" on `B1` look for edits on `A1`.